# How to Initialize a vector<typeinfo>?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am able to do this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

But I am not able to do this:

```
std::vector<const type_info&> ClassBlackList = { typeid(Class1), typeid(Class2) };
```

compiler says pointer to reference is illegal
or

```
std::vector<const type_info> ClassBlackList = { typeid(Class1), typeid(Class2) };
```

compiler says Error C2338   The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator is ill-formed.

or

```
std::vector<type_info> ClassBlackList = { typeid(Class1), typeid(Class2) };
```

Compiler says:
Error   C2280   'type_info::type_info(const type_info &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

I am able not able to do push_back either.
What is the solution to have a vector or list of type_info?

Comment: `std::type_index`

Comment: An `std::vector` cannot contain references in any circumstances.   A `type_info` is neither copy constructable or assignable, so cannot be stored in a vector either.   Try storing some data from the `type_info` structure in a vector, such as (depending on your needs) a `std::vector<std::string>` (which can be initialised with `type_info::name()`, but bear in mind the content of the names are implementation-defined) or - since C++11 - `std::vector<std::type_index>` or `std::vector<std::size_t>` (which can be initialised with the `type_info::hash()` member)

Comment: Thanks. My usage is just want to compare later with a class against this the vector for equality. I currently have vector<string> and compare class name by string. So vector<type_index> or hash() also will work for my case? Which do you think is best approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can use pointers

```
std::vector<const std::type_info*> v = { &typeid(Class1), &typeid(Class2) };
```

This is valid because `typeid` returns a reference to an object with static storage duration.

Comment: Thanks. But my next step is to check if Class3 is present in the ClassBlackList. I initially thought of using std::find without having a loop. Is there any easy way for this when you use pointers?

Comment: `std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), &typeid(Class3));` or if you want to compare `type_info` instances `std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto* info) { return *info == typeid(Class3); });`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a vector of references, for several fundamental reasons. C++ simply does not work this way. You can, however, employ `std::reference_wrapper` to get pretty much the same result:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>> avec;

    auto &t=typeid(A);

    avec.push_back(t);

    const std::type_info &i=avec[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have arrays of references so you could wrap them in  [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)s:

```
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>> ClassBlackList = {
    typeid(Class1), 
    typeid(Class2) 
};
```

The name `ClassBlackList` implies that you will search it a lot and also that the elements in the list are to be unique. In that case, you may want to use a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead.

Example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <set>

struct Class1 {};
struct Class2 {};
struct Class3 {};

struct comp { // a functor to compare reference wrapped type_info's
    std::size_t operator()(const std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>& lhs,
                       const std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>& rhs) const
    {
        return std::less<const std::type_info*>{}(&lhs.get(), &rhs.get());
    }
};

int main() {   
    std::set<std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>, comp> ClassBlackList = {
        typeid(Class1), 
        typeid(Class2) 
    };

    // try to insert typeid(Class3) twice, it only succeeds the first time

    auto[it1, inserted1] = ClassBlackList.insert(typeid(Class3));
    std::cout << "inserted: " << inserted1 << '\n';

    auto[it2, inserted2] = ClassBlackList.insert(typeid(Class3));
    std::cout << "inserted: " << inserted2 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
inserted: 1
inserted: 0
```

Comment: Yes the classes in BlackList are unique, but the aim is to make sure the class3 is not in the BlackList. Thanks for this solution, but I just feel that this std::reference_wrapper makes it slightly complicated in readablity. I am currently using vector<string> from type_info.name().

Comment: @KARTHIKMS Using a `set` you can still [`std::set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) to see if `typeid(class3)` is not in the blacklist - and it's usually a lot quicker than finding it in an unsorted `vector`. The `reference_wrapper` adds a bit of complexity. It's essentially a `class reference_wrapper { T* obj };` that tries to behave like an automatic but keeps a pointer (to be able to store it in arrays). It takes up the same space as a pointer.

Comment: @KARTHIKMS If you add or remove classes to the blacklist often - use a `std::set` otherwise, using a `std::vector` may not be so bad. You could keep the `vector` sorted and then `std::binary_search` in it instead of using a `std::set`

Comment: All the answers here are helpful in a way. But what I did out of it is in my above comment. That is why I did not fix one answer as accepted. and instead clicked thumbs up. Thank you once again.