# Is it possible to create an array of std::type_info?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, types, std

I'm importing data from a memory map and datatypes are mapped to certain integer values.

This is an example of a switch case where I use a template to create the value with the correct type. However, this switch case has more code and lots of other cases.

```
void function(std::vector<int> impTypes, int idxImpValue)
{
  // impTypes = array of imported datatypes
  // idxImpValue = index of imported value
  switch(impTypes[idxImpValue])
  {
    case 0: { double value = getValue<double>(idxImpValue); }
      break;

    case 6: { int value = getValue<int>(idxImpValue); }
      break;

    case 23: { uint64_t value = getValue<uint64_t>(idxImpValue); }
      break;
  return 0;
}
```

Besides having big switch cases, I also have lots of them, which makes it kind of painful whenever I need to change something.

I was wondering if I could get rid of the switch case and if I could somehow pass the type to the template according to that integer value, hence why it would be great if I could create an array of std::type_info.

```
void function(std::vector<std::type_info> impTypes, int idxImpValue)
{
  impTypes[idxImpValue] value = getValue<impTypes[idxImpValue]>(idxImpValue);
  return 0
}
```

Comment: We might need more details of what you're trying to achieve. You can't use a variable as a template parameter

Comment: What will you need to do with the extracted `value`? Do you use same code to handle them or you use different code in different cases?

Comment: @AlanBirtles The data is imported from a memory map that provides a way to identify the type of the variable. I get the value, create the value with the correct data type and display it.

Comment: @PengGuanwen the code is the same for every datatype except std::string
What I want to achieve is to have the minimum amount of cases possible. Since code is repeated through all cases expect one, I thought there might be a way to create the "value" variable with the correct data type without having to manually create it in every case.

Comment: [How to Initialize a vector<typeinfo>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666574/how-to-initialize-a-vectortypeinfo).

Comment: @edumir So what you really need is not making an array of `type_info`, but to avoid duplicate code in switch cases, please edit the title so other users can vote to reopen your question.

Comment: @PengGuanwen thank you! I've already found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create an array of `std::type_info`?

No, because `std::type_info` has no constructors and, hence, is neither move- nor copy-constructible.

However, you can have a [`std::vector<std::type_index>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) and use it as a database of types.