# How to declare a container of types

Tags: c++, templates

I have several template classes/functions that should only be instantiated with a short list of types. I wanted to do a vector (or any container) of the types, but I can't find how to, I'm expecting something like:

```
std::vector<std::type_info> myTypes = {typeid(int)};
template void myFunc<myTypes[0]>();
```

This code doesn't compile! I'm looking for the right syntax for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666574/how-to-initialize-a-vectortypeinfo

Comment: I would advise you to use `std::type_index` instead, it's a more convenient `sd::type_info` wrapper (you don't have to bother about references).

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is, but a container of `std::type_info` is almost certainly not a solution for it.

Comment: If that dupe answers your question then fine, but if it winds up not working (because it looks like you want to use it to instantiate a template) then give me a ping as I have a solution that will work for that.

Comment: By the way, the function declaration cannot work this way, a `std::type_info` of an `int` is not an `int` (maybe fill actual instances in the vector and then declare the function arguments with `decltype`). But anyway, it's very strange to declare a function without directly giving the expected arguments types. It sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @Fareanor I'm lloking for a nice way of telling my template functions that they all only have the same 3 or 4 types

Comment: @NathanOliver Ping (?)

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not think it is a duplicate indeed

Comment: @Ivan What you want then is to have a constraint over the type, maybe with concepts or with the good olds `std::enable_if` or `static_assert` with `std::is_same` type traits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::tuple` to create a type list like

```
using type_list = std::tuple<int, double>;
template <std::size_t I>
using type_list_element_t = std::tuple_element_t<I, type_list>;
```

and then you can use it to instantiate your template like

```
template void myFunc<type_list_element_t<0>>();
```

which instantiates `myFunc` for `int`.

Comment: `std::tuple_element_t` for brevity

Comment: @Caleth Good call.  I looked it up [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) and the `_t` alias wasn't mentioned so I though it didn't exist.  Turns out I just needed to visit the main page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple_element